# Closure compiler throwing error on Mustache Tag

Tags: javascript, mustache, google-closure-compiler

I have a mustache tag in my code `{{{customers}}}`. When i try to compile the file with closure, it throws an error.

```
C:/index.js:289: 
ERROR - Parse error. '}' expected
    customers:{{{customers}}},

               ^
```

How can i tell the compiler to ignore this string?

Comment: Do you need anything else on this?

Comment: Nah, if the bottom line is that Closure compiler expects valid Javascript, then i simply won't compile the file with templates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know mustache beyond a quick glance at some pages describing it.  It seems to be a template system, which (I'm guessing a bit here) means that it takes "mustache syntax" and outputs JavaScript (looks like it can output in other languages as well).

Closure compiler is expecting valid JavaScript.  If there is still "mustache syntax" then you haven't processed the template to become valid JavaScript yet.